# Atom key combination to add an html tag to a selected text

Tags: atom-editor, emmet

I saw that is possible with the atom editor (with emmet plugin installed) first select something of your html code (for example an paragraph), and the you can write an tag html like `<label>` and the atom edit put the selected paragraph inside the label: `<label>some selected text</label>` in one step

I would like to know what is the key sequence or I what I should do in Atom after I select a text to write an tag HTML that enclose the selected text.

Comment: So you read the instruction @ https://atom.io/packages/emmet and after that and looking at how the current shortcuts are created you are stuck?  A  quick google also seems to return a plethora of information about this editor.

Comment: Yes, after that I did n´t found the combination to do that with Atom, so I decide to write the question here. I am not sure if it is a shortcut of atom, or emmet, and I was looking in both types of tutorials/videos. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emmet has function of "[Wrap with Abbreviation](https://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/)", the shortcut of Atom in Mac is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> (you can check "Atom -> Preference -> Install -> emmet -> Keybindins -> emmet:wrap-with-abbreviation")

There is another solution --  installing plugin "[Atom wrap in tag](https://atom.io/packages/atom-wrap-in-tag)"

Comment: thanks! That´s was what I was looking and asking for! the option with Emet - wrap withabbreviation" do the job